# Calling linux utilities with options from within a Bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, find, utilities, wc

This is my first Bash script so forgive me if this question is trivial. I need to count the number of files within a specified directory $HOME/.junk. I thought this would be simple and assumed the following would work:

```
numfiles= find $HOME/.junk -type f | wc -l
echo "There are $numfiles files in the .junk directory."
```

Typing `find $HOME/.junk -type f | wc -l` at the command line works exactly how I expected it to, simply returning the number of files. Why is this not working when it is entered within my script? Am I missing some special notation when it comes to passing options to the utilities?

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Note that your 'find' command was executed with an environment variable 'numfiles' set to the empty string.  This can be useful when you want to do it (you can set an env var for the duration of one command without affecting the parent shell), but is a surprise when you don't know that it happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to surround it with backticks:

```
numfiles=`find $HOME/.junk -type f | wc -l`
```

The term for this is [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html).

Comment: @Kyle: You're welcome.  As you encounter more issues learning Bash scripting (or if you just want to "learn ahead"), I highly recommend reading through the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide as linked in my answer.

Comment: I will definitely put that guide to good use, thanks again Mark.

Comment: Or, much better, use `$(find $HOME/.junk -type f | wc -l)`.  There are fewer problems with nesting the `$(...)` than with back quotes.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using bash you can also use $() for command substitution, like so:

```
numfiles=$(find $HOME/.junk -type f | wc -l)
```

I find this to be slightly more readable than backquotes, as well as having the ability to nest several commands inside one another.

Answer (score 1):

with bash 4 (if you want recursive)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
for file in **
do
 ((i++))
done
echo "total files: $i"
```

if not

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s dotglob
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *
do 
  ((i++))
done 
echo "total files: $i"
```